# how to test contract without deploy every time?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I started to learn solidity 4 days ago. 
Every time I follow this steps:

1 - Open remix Solidity Ide site
2 - Set ropsten test network (inject web3)
3 - deploy
4 - some react coding with web3 js
5 - try some calls from my frontend app or from blue/red button in remix site

All seems to work but for example if compiler will not find error in code but I wrong some logic, I need to kill existing contract with its kill function and then deploy a new contract with the edit.

I know there is truffle for unit test and I hope to use in the future but I need a "manual" test to reproduce manual interaction with metamask.

Comment: Remix has an inbuilt Javascript VM for rapid iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All seems to work but for example if compiler will not find error in code but I wrong some logic, I need to kill existing contract with its kill function and then deploy a new contract with the edit.
>
> but I need a "manual" test to reproduce manual interaction with metamask.

Normally developers start with testrpc (now rebranded as ganache) which is a local simulation to test the contracts of its functionality.

If you are using the remix ide, the javascript VM can also be used for faster testing iterations.

I recommend to only switch over to the manual interaction with metamask once any of the above testing methods produce good results. This saves a lot of time in redoing the killing and redeployment of contracts.

Also if you are planning to move over to truffle, it is better to start now itself as it offers the test driven development using mocha style scripting which can be done in javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use local ethereum node for testing on your machine. I recommend [ganache](https://truffleframework.com/docs/ganache/quickstart). After you start it, you can connect to it at local, like `HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545`.
`

Comment: No, it will deploy empty blockchain on your machine starting from block 0. It will have only your transactions and contracts, which will give you instant transaction times and as much ether for testing as you want.